# spring mvc annotation - dummy form variable

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, annotations

I have a form with two select boxes that are used to move values from one box to another. I need to submit values only from second select box to my ModelAttribute. How do i prevent spring mvc from complaining about "unable to bind" on my first selectbox.

Comment: Are you using `<form:select>`, or just a raw HTML one?

Comment: I am using <form:select>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you populating the dummy select control using spring binding? If not, for example if you are using ReferenceData to populate it, you could use an html select tag and omit the name attribute, which would mean it would not be submitted with the form.